# Does this make a VLAN loop?

Tags: switch, vlan, loop

I have a network that provides external IP addresses through VLANs. The same network also provides VLANs for internal use. Roughs map (not all switches):

```
                                VLAN 20 (for internal subnet)
            |switchB|----|switchE|----computers  
                |
Router------|switchA| 
                |                 VLAN 10 (with external IP)
            |switchC|----|switchD|----|Firewall|---server 
                             |            |
                             --------------
                                  VLAN 20 (For internal subnet)
```

My question, does this make a loop that will bring down the VLAN 20?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the firewall is a Layer 3 firewall (and not in layer 2 mode like some firewalls are) this won't generate a loop. If it will work, that's a totally different question, that depends on your actual configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The firewall is layer 3. Fore some reason VLAN20 goes down sometimes. When VLAN 20 goes down the firewall is reachable from out side but not the server.

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs on switchD when VLAN 20 goes down?

Comment: No, not what I can see. Do you have any tip for what I should be looking for?